# Fast synchronised cout for multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, cout, lag

Recently I ran into a rather common problem about using cout in a multithreading application but with a little twist. I've got several callbackfunctions which get called by external hardware via a driver. Main objective of the callback funtions is to receive some data and store it in a queue and signal a processing-task as soon as a certain amout of datasets got collected. The callback-function needs to run as fast as possible in order to respond to the hardware in soft realtime.
My problem is this: From time to time my queue gets full and I have to handle this case by printing out a warning to the console (hard requirement). As I work with several threads I've created a wrapper function which uses a mutex to synchronise cout. Unfortunately, in some cases waiting for access to cout can take so much time that my callback function doesn't end fast enough to respond to the hardware before a timeout. My solution was to use a atomic variable for each possible error to count the number of occurences and a further task to check these variables periodically and print out the messages afterwards, but I'm pretty sure that this is not the best approach to solve my performance problems.
Are there any general approaches for this type of problem?
Any recommendations how I could improve or simplify my solution?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't write output in the hotpath.

Instead, queue up the stuff you want to log (prefereably raw data rather than a fully formatted string).  Have another OOB thread running which picks up this stuff and logs it.

Comment: That is what I'm already doing, but I thought it's a bit too much for such a "simple" problem. Are there any smarter/shorter approaches?

Comment: @Chili this is the solution I would use. If it is time sensitive then doing as little IO as possible on the thread is a very good thing, since IO is not a fast operation. Plus it's not terribly hard to implement.

Comment: Ok, then I'll keep my current solution. Thank you